# Constraints on Label/Button to show entire text of label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Completely new to Swift.

I want to have my text above the "Get Started" button, but to show all the text. In the original code, I have the content where I'd like it, but I can't it to show the entire label text. What edits can make to this so that it shows the entirety of the text?

With original code:

```
func setupViews() {
    self.view.addSubview(lblTitle)
    lblTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive=true
    lblTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
    lblTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive=true
    lblTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive=true

    self.view.addSubview(btnGetStarted)
    btnGetStarted.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true
    btnGetStarted.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive=true
    btnGetStarted.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
    btnGetStarted.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
}

let lblTitle: UILabel = {
    let lbl=UILabel()
    lbl.text="Bacon ipsum dolor amet shankle filet mignon bacon shank frankfurter buffalo. Swine andouille burgdoggen jerky. Kevin meatball jerky tri-tip tail, biltong meatloaf fatback cupim pork chop."
    lbl.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
    lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 46)
    lbl.numberOfLines=2
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return lbl
}()

let btnGetStarted: UIButton = {
    let btn=UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor=UIColor.orange
    btn.layer.cornerRadius=5
    btn.layer.masksToBounds=true
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnGetStartedAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Both the label and the button have minimumScaleFactor property as well as a Bool property to fit width. Try using that.

```
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

The label has the same properties to scale the font.

```
 lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
 lbl.numberOfLines = 2
 lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: This started to fix it - it's still formatting the text strangely, in that it's clearly boxed in with some constraint, but I can work from here. Thanks!

Comment: iOS 11 does have a strange word wrap that you might be seeing

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing the `height` of the label and add `topAnchor` to the button
2. Add `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, `numberOfLines=0`, `sizeToFit()`  to the label

   ```
   func setupViews() {
       self.view.addSubview(lblTitle)
       lblTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive=true
       lblTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
       lblTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive=true
       lblTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive=true

       self.view.addSubview(btnGetStarted)
       btnGetStarted.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive=true
       btnGetStarted.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true
       btnGetStarted.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive=true
       btnGetStarted.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
       btnGetStarted.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
   }

   let lblTitle: UILabel = {
       let lbl=UILabel()
       lbl.text="Bacon ipsum dolor amet shankle filet mignon bacon shank frankfurter buffalo. Swine andouille burgdoggen jerky. Kevin meatball jerky tri-tip tail, biltong meatloaf fatback cupim pork chop."
       lbl.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
       lbl.textAlignment = .center
       lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 46)
       lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
       lbl.numberOfLines=0
       lbl.sizeToFit()
       lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
       return lbl
   }()
   ```

Comment: It still cuts off the text

Comment: Did u add `sizeToFit` after changing the numerOfLines ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Looks to be edited to add what I put below previously. Also sizeToFit is unneeded as it is being governed by autolayout.

Comment: Every problem has multiple solutions, it depends on the user which one to choose for their need.